Brightness adjustment steps on both OSes too large now on a laptop dual-booted to Windows and Ubuntu
I recently had an Ubuntu partition installed on my Windows machine. This is a laptop I use for work, and I needed Linux for a work-related task.

Before: On straight Windows, the lowest brightness setting using the keyboard buttons used to be very dim. This is the setting I always use.
After: The Ubuntu side's brightness controls have a lowest brightness setting that is much brighter - and on the Windows side it is now the same as on the Ubuntu side. Both OS seem to have the same number of steps for brightness adjustment (10), but the lowest setting got brighter.

This is something that is a serious need for me at the moment, as I am suffering from after-effects of a head injury, and the light triggers severe migraines. So I need to figure out a way to go back to the previous settings, or increase the number of steps so the lowest brightness is dimmer.
I am assuming there is a hardware communication issue, that I am hoping can be fixed somewhere? If I fix it on the Linux side, would it also affect Windows (where I would do most of my work)? And what is the fix that would affect both OS?

As this is related to your health, I would recommend put the computer away, send it to a professional to do an OS reset or something similar.
After you get better you can try hacking with it again.
